# jQuery onclick event working incorrectly when DOM is modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm having some difficulty understanding jQuery (v1.11) in regards to events and how DOM interaction affects those events.

**The setup:**

I create a grid of inline-blocks with the class "letter" and watch for clicks:

```
$('.letter).on('click',function(){ // do something })
```

When I click on one, it expands to the size of its parent container.

**The problem:**

Even though I remove the class "letter", the div still responds to click events. Ideally, I want to expand the div to show more information, then allow it to shrink back into place when the user is done.

Here is my html and the **fiddle is at the bottom.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
        *, *:before, *:after {
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .square { 
            font-size: 20px;
            color: white;
            padding: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #69f;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .grid {
            width: 390px;
            padding: 5px;
            }
        .row { padding-top: 5px; }
        .square.empty { background-color: #87afff; }
        .square-highlight { background-color: #36f; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- begin content -->
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="rows">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="square empty"></div>
                <div class="square empty"></div>
                <div class="square empty"></div>
                <div class="square empty"></div>
                <div class="square empty"></div>
                <div class="square empty"></div>
                <div class="square letter">a</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="square letter">b</div>
                <div class="square letter">c</div>
                <div class="square letter">d</div>
                <div class="square letter">e</div>
                <div class="square letter">f</div>
                <div class="square letter">g</div>
                <div class="square letter">h</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="square letter">i</div>
                <div class="square letter">j</div>
                <div class="square letter">k</div>
                <div class="square letter">l</div>
                <div class="square letter">m</div>
                <div class="square letter">n</div>
                <div class="square letter">o</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="square letter">p</div>
                <div class="square letter">q</div>
                <div class="square letter">r</div>
                <div class="square letter">s</div>
                <div class="square letter">t</div>
                <div class="square letter">u</div>
                <div class="square letter">v</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="square letter">w</div>
                <div class="square letter">x</div>
                <div class="square letter">y</div>
                <div class="square letter">z</div>
                <div class="square empty"></div>
                <div class="square empty"></div>
                <div class="square empty"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.letter').hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('square-highlight');
        },function(){
            $(this).removeClass('square-highlight');
        });

        $(".letter").not('.large').on('click',function(){
            $(this)
                .addClass('large')
                .css('position','absolute')
                .stop()
                .animate({
                    height: $('.rows').height()-5, 
                    width: $('.rows').width(),
                    top: $('.rows').position().top+5,
                    left: $('.rows').position().left
                },"fast")
                .append('<input type="button" name="Save" value="save" />');
        });
        $(".large").on('click',function(){
            alert('test');
        });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aKpLQ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event is bound to the element during `$(document).ready` using the selectors and the state of the elements at that time.  Changing an element's class does not change the events that have been bound to it.

To change the event, you would have to unbind the click event and bind it with a new event.  Alternatively, you could use the same event handler function with a conditional which behaves differently depending on the current state of the element.  Something like:

```
$(".letter").on('click',function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('large')){
    alert('test');
    $(this).removeClass('large');
  } else
    $(this)
      .addClass('large')
      .css('position','absolute')
      .stop()
      .animate({
        height: $('.rows').height()-5, 
        width: $('.rows').width(),
        top: $('.rows').position().top+5,
        left: $('.rows').position().left
      },"fast")
      .append('<input type="button" name="Save" value="save" />');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Events are matched once on document ready, when none of them has class large, so the event with large selector will not work. You could check if element has class large onClick
 http://jsfiddle.net/84gba/1/

```
    $(".letter").on('click',function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('large'))
        {
         alert("test");   
        }
        else
        {
        $(this)
            .addClass('large')
            .css('position','absolute')
            .css('z-index','100')
            .stop()
            .animate({
                height: $('.rows').height()-5, 
                width: $('.rows').width(),
                top: $('.rows').position().top+5,
                left: $('.rows').position().left
            },"fast")
            .append('<input type="button" name="Save" value="save" />');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) for this kind of stuff, here is an example close to your markup:

```
$('.rows').on('click',function(e){

var $tar = $(e.target);
 if($tar.is('.letter')){
    if($tar.is('.large')){
        // Do Stuff
    } else {
        // Do other stuff
    }
});
```

And this will also work if you add or remove a '.letter' in your list, which is very cool.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aKpLQ/1/ so that it works. I would suggest you adopt a pattern of creating and destroying a div element everytime the user clicks on it. This would allow you a lot more flexibility without interfering with you existing rows. But anyways this works as well, just might get headachy if you're trying to do more stuff. Make sure you remember the event.currentTarget, it is very useful when you're trying to figure out which element fired the event.

Here is the code part in case you're too lazy to click on a link ;)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.letter').hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('square-highlight');
        },function(){
            $(this).removeClass('square-highlight');
        });

        $(".letter").on('click',function(e){
            if(!$(e.currentTarget).hasClass("large")){
            $(e.currentTarget)
                .addClass('large')
                .css('position','absolute')
                .css('z-index','100')
                .stop()
                .animate({
                    height: $('.rows').height()-5, 
                    width: $('.rows').width(),
                    top: $('.rows').position().top+5,
                    left: $('.rows').position().left
                },"fast")
                .append('<input type="button" name="Save" value="save" />');
            }
        });
        $(".large").on('click',function(){
            alert('test');
        });
    });
```